# How to get PostgreSQL version using PHP functions

Tags: php

How do I get PostgreSQL and TOMCAT version using PHP functions. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I have found in this link [Re: Determing Postgres version](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/GNELIHDDFBOCMGBFGEFOMENFCAAA.chriskl@familyhealth.com.au) and the code is

```
$sql = "SELECT version();";
pg_send_query($dbconnection, $sql);
```

And my machine returns

```
PostgreSQL 8.4.20 on i386-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 32-bit
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pg_version](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-version.php) to find the PostgreSQL version.

To find the Tomcat varsion you can open the file `catalina.out` and search for the pattern:

```
Apache Tomcat/<version>
```

A typical example is:

```
Apache Tomcat/6.0.13
```

Comment: Need to check using PHP functions only...Please

Comment: Apache Tomcat? It is only for java, the question is about PHP.